# Is there a way to avoid wasNull() method?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, resultset

I have a big `ResultSet` (getting from a `JDBC` query) of few thousand rows. Using each of these rows, I have to instantiate an `Object`, setting fields of it according to the fields of this result set. Now, as we all know, the `getXXX()` methods of this `JDBC API` return `0` if that particular column was `null`. So for each field of each row, I have to do a `wasNull()` before setting the value in my `object`, which looks pretty ugly and may be is not efficient as well. So, is there any other way by which I can avoid it?

Apart from JDBC, if there is some entirely different, standard, commonly used way, I am open to know about that as well.

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

```
patientInput.setRaceCodeId(patients.getShort("race_code_id"));  
if(patients.wasNull())
    patientInput.setRaceCodeId(null);
```

`patients` is a `ResultSet`. `patientInput` is an `object`. This is the code which I am trying to avoid. I mean, everytime I do a `getXXX()`,  and do a `setXXX()`, I have to check again that what I got from `ResultSet` was not `null`. If it was, then set that object field as `null`, as `getXXX()` returns `0` in that case.

Comment: What are you setting null values as when they are encountered using wasNull?

Comment: @Gordon Murray Dent: I am sorry, i didn't get your question well. if you are asking what do i set the field in my object if the corresponding column is found null, in that case i set that object field as `null`.

Comment: Can I see a sample of code please. It is difficult to give useful advice without seeing your problem in context.

Comment: @Gordon Murray Dent: please see the question, I have added sample code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok. I believe there are two possible approaches to 'tidying' up your code. However, this could come down to a difference of opinion as to what is tidy!

Solution 1 - replace **getXXX()** with **getObject()** which returns null e.g.

```
Short s = (Short)patients.getObject("race_code_id");
patientInput.setRaceCodeId(s);
```

Solution 2 - write a *generic wrapper method* that retrieves nullable values

```
protected final <T> T getNullableValue(T returnType, String colName, ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {  
  Object colValue = rs.getObject(colName);  
  return (T) colValue;  
}

final static Integer INT = 0;
final static Short SHORT = 0;
.
.
.
patientInput.setRaceCodeId(getNullableValue(SHORT,"race_code_id",patients));
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do it to each field, only to fields that are numeric and, possibly, boolean, and are declared as nullable in your database. It happens not as frequently as you fear.

If you absolutely hate writing such code, you can try switching to an ORM library, for example, Hibernate.

Comment: almost all fields are numeric, about 20 :( And the code looks pretty ugly. I am sure there is some better way to avoid this.

Comment: @Bhushan: I don't believe checking wasNull() 20 times in one place is too ugly. If this code is all over your application, try to encapsulate "ugliness" in one class or in as little classes as makes sense. If this is still too ugly, consider switching to an ORM library that would hide that kind of details from other parts of your application.